# singleton, metaclass and error during instantiation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I needed to create a singleton in for my code. So I followed [these instructions, method 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python).

Here is the code that I have:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

def MyCfg(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton
    def __init__(self, p1 = 1, p2 = 2):
        # Some code

my_cfg = MyCfg()
```

However whenI run this code, I get a following error:

```
TypeError: MyCfg() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I'm not new to `python` and programming but I never worked at with `python` at this level. I've been trying to understand what exactly happens in `Singleton` class but I can't figure out.

Would anyone be able to explain why this code generates an error?

Comment: @shaktimaan It didn't work. Still getting the same error.

Comment: `MyCfg` is a function, not a class. Change the `def` to `class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
def MyCfg(object)
```

I am pretty sure you mean:

```
class MyCfg(object)
```

The error you are seeing (`TypeError: MyCfg() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`) is because with your current code, you are defining a *function* called `MyCfg` that takes a single argument (which you are not providing).

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. I just figured that out.